# Match URL's which do NOT have a specific prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, image, url

i match image urls inside a string with the following regular expression in javascript:

```
/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]?(\.(jpe?g|png|gif))/ig
```

with the String.replace function, i wrap all matches inside an -tag.

in a second step i'd like to match all urls, which do *not* have the above file extensions as prefix. my first intention was to use the ?!-operator like this:

```
/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]?(?!\.(jpe?g|png|gif))/ig
```

unfortunatly, this does no work. tried different variations of this expression, but with now results.

thanks for any help in advance,
manuel

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking about javascript, I think something like this could help :

```
var url_re = "\\b(https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/[\\-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\\-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|]?"
var re = new RegExp( "^(?!.*"+url_re+"\.(jpe?g|png|gif)).*"+url_re+"\.[a-z0-9_]+" , 'gi' )
```

Comment: that would work if my string only contains one url. but i have a string with a text, which could containe no, one or multiple urls... thanks anyway for your suggestion

Comment: See my new answer if it could help you?

Comment: does not work either ... tested it with regexpal.com; seems to match only one url, and only if its the only one thing inside the string

Comment: Why not test on your browser instead? I tested with FF & everything works properly.

Comment: using firefox too ;) i'll try no another way: just match all URL's in my string and use a callback together with the String.replace function